# Range-based intersection of n-number of arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, intersection

Lets say I have the following three arrays:

```
[
  [100, 110, 200, 300, 400],
  [40, 90, 99, 150, 200],
  [101, 202, 404, 505]
]
```

how would I go about writing a function `getIntersectingRanges(arrays, range)` which would return all ranges of max 'width' of `range` containing 1 or more elements from all arrays.

So, if `range=15` then it would return `[[100, 90, 99, 101], [100, 110, 99, 101], [200, 200, 202]]`. Each of those arrays contains at least one element from each input range and the total 'width' of the range is less or equal to 15 (first one is 11, second one 11 as well and the third one just 3).

It's conceptually incredibly simple but I have been having a really hard to figuring out how to write such a function. Like I am not looking for a fully fleshed out solution, all I need is the basis of the algorithm allowing me to do so (though I will obviously also gladly accept a fully written function).

---

As some people seem to have a problem understanding this, let me give a few more simple examples (though writing these by hand is a bit hard, so excuse me if I make a mistake somewhere):

> input:   `[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [55, 84]]`
> range:  `5`
> output: `[[50, 55], [55, 60], [80, 84]]`
>
> input:   `[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50]]`
> range:  `10`
> output: `[[30, 40]]`
>
> input:   `[[15, 30, 699], [16, 800], [10, 801], [11, 803]]`
> range:  `10`
> output: `[[15, 16, 10, 11]]`

---

So my approach has been to first only take the first two arrays, next search for all elements from the first array in the second array ± range. So far it seems to make sense, but given this start it seems impossible to match both the first and the second result from the example above... so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NinaScholz Because that's the minimal case that makes clear what the intention is. I could just as easily have 1, 2 or 8. Ah, for output it's just by chance, those are the three different ranges I was able to find by hand of with a width of 15 containing at least one element from each input array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Don't get what you mean with your last edit.

Comment: @NinaScholz Well, one array is a bit of a special case, as `[[100], [110], [200], [300], [400], [100, 110]]` are all technically correct (each returning array conrtains at least one element from each (a single one) input array and has a 'width' of less than 15, so if anything: do ignore the n=1 case... I will probably handle that one seperatedly.

Comment: If I got it right, the result you wrote in your example is intersection of all array one elements with other two arrays. Don't you need array two and array three intersect results? Also, I don't get how you picked 110 to be part of intersect in your second result array, but not in first?

Comment: @msmolcic In the first the range is from 90 to 101, in the second from 99 to 110. So the first includes 90 but not 110, the second includes 110 but not 90. They are different ranges, but both satisfy the rule of intersecting with all input arrays and having a range of at most 15. Including both 90 and 110 would give a range of 20 > 15.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I got the ranging part wrong at first. I thought you're looking for numbers in other arrays ± 15 from current element value.

Comment: @msmolcic Once you get it it's pretty simple I think conceptually, but yeah, I spend quite a bit of time struggling with how to word this question and it even garnered a close vote for being unclear :O Either way, did add a few more really simple examples that do not show the 'problem' area (multiple overlapping output ranges) as my first answer did.

Comment: Is your range inclusive or exclusive? I mean, can 40 and 55 match as result, in your example they can't, but maybe it's a mistake..

Comment: @msmolcic Oh, oops, I might have been inconsistent when I was doing it by hand. But in principle my code so far was inclusive, however as long as the code is consistent both are fine, in the end the important thing is that I come to comprehend how to do this.

Comment: In your first example (the one with range = 15), are you supposed to get `[100, 99, 101]` as well? it satisfies the conditions (all arrays, within 15) - Or is the requirement to *only* get the superset `[100, 90, 99, 101]`?

Comment: @Amit Ideally only the superset, but doing the filtering later myself would have been easy enough, the current accepted solution is doing the opposite: It misses the superset but only returns the subsets... still though, I think I will be able to get my code running with that even~ (just makes some processing later along the way a bit harder). Will be posting a small bounty in two days in principle to reward the current answer, but if you feel like having a go at coming up with a better solution: feel free to.

Comment: Leaving myself a comment so that I can find this tomorrow: http://jsperf.com/findranges

Comment: @DavidMulder I updated it with my updated solution here: http://jsperf.com/findranges/3. I hope you're checking for correctness before performance :p

Comment: Added another large-size performance test: http://jsperf.com/findranges/6 - with Nina's code giving incorrect result, but still included for performance comparison.

Answer (score 4):

This solution features an object with the values as key and as value the indices of the array of the given arrays.

The additional approach is the speeding of the lookup items, which have a short circuit if the index is outside the area of a possible finding.

> **Example**
>
> Given array:
>
> ```
> [
>     [100, 110, 200, 300, 400],
>     [40, 90, 99, 150, 200],
>     [101, 202, 404, 505]
> ]
> ```
>
> Given range: 15
>
> First sort the given values ascending.
>
> Then iterate from the smallest value to the highest and look if values in range are in all arrays.
>
> ```
> Array Values                                               Comment
> ----- ---------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
> 0                100     110     200     300 400
> 1     40  90  99             150 200
> 2                    101             202         404 505
>        1                                                   here is no other value in this range
>            1   1   0   2                                <- first group, values are in all arrays
>                1   0   2   0                            <- second group, values are in all arrays
>                    0   2   0                               only values of two arrays
>                        2   0                               only values of two arrays
>                                1                           here is no other value in this range
>                                   01   2                <- third group, values are in all arrays
>                                        2                   here is no other value in this range
>                                            0               here is no other value in this range
>                                                0   2       only values of two arrays
>                                                       2    here is no other value in this range
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> [
>     [[100], [90, 99], [101]],
>     [[100, 110], [99], [101]],
>     [[200], [200], [202]]
> ]
> ```

```js
function intersection(arrays, range) {
    var result = [],                   // result array
        items = [],                    // all distinct items from arrays
        indices = {},                  // object for the array indices
        temp,                          // temp array, for pushing a result
        i,                             // counter for pushing values to temp
        left = 0, pos = 0, lastPos,    // look up range
        allArrays,                     // temporary array for indicating if index is included
        arraysLength = arrays.length,  // arrays length
        itemLength,                    // length of all items
        leftValue,                     // literally the value from the left range
        emptyArrays;                   // template for the test if all arrays are used

    emptyArrays = Array.apply(Array, { length: arraysLength });
    arrays.forEach(function (a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (item) {
            indices[item] = indices[item] || [];
            indices[item].push(i);
        });
    });
    items = Object.keys(indices).map(Number).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    itemLength = items.length;
    do {
        temp = [];
        allArrays = emptyArrays.slice(0);
        leftValue = items[left];
        pos = left;
        while (pos < itemLength && items[pos] <= range + leftValue) {
            temp.push(items[pos]);
            indices[items[pos]].forEach(function (i) {
                allArrays[i] = true;
            });
            pos++;
        }
        pos !== lastPos && allArrays.every(function (a) { return a; }) && result.push(temp);
        left++;
        lastPos = pos;
    } while (pos < itemLength);
    return result;
}

function test(arrays, range) {
    var result = intersection(arrays, range);
    document.write("<br>arrays:", JSON.stringify(arrays));
    document.write("<br>range:", range);
    document.write("<br>result:", JSON.stringify(result));
    document.write("<br>---");
}


test([[100, 110, 200, 300, 400], [40, 90, 99, 150, 200], [101, 202, 404, 505]], 15);
test([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [55, 84]], 5);
test([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50]], 10);
test([[15, 30, 699], [16, 800], [10, 801], [11, 803]], 10);

// taken from the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/a/32868439/1447675 from DzinX
var LARGE_TEST_SIZE = 1000,
    largeTest = function () {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < LARGE_TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
            var innerArray = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < LARGE_TEST_SIZE; ++j) {
                innerArray.push((i + j) * 10);
            }
            array.push(innerArray);
        }
        return array;
    }(),
    startTime;

startTime = Date.now();
document.write('<br>' + intersection(largeTest, 20).length + '<br>');
document.write('Duration [ms]: ' + (Date.now() - startTime) + '<br>');
```

## Comparision with the solution from DzinX

I just changed the `console.log` to `document.write('<br>' ...`.

Please watch `Duration` in the result windows.

```js
function findRanges(arrays, range) {

    // Gather all items into one array:
    var items = [];
    arrays.forEach(function (array, arrayNumber) {
        array.forEach(function (item) {
            items.push({
                value: item,
                arrayNumber: arrayNumber
            });
        });
    });

    items.sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.value - right.value;
    });

    var countByArray = [];
    arrays.forEach(function () {
        countByArray.push(0);
    });

    var arraysIncluded = 0;

    var i = 0,
      j = 0, // inclusive
      spread = 0,
      arrayCount = arrays.length,
      itemCount = items.length,
      result = [];

    function includeItem(pos) {
        var arrayNumber = items[pos].arrayNumber;
        ++countByArray[arrayNumber];
        if (countByArray[arrayNumber] === 1) {
            ++arraysIncluded;
        }
    }

    function excludeItem(pos) {
        var arrayNumber = items[pos].arrayNumber;
        --countByArray[arrayNumber];
        if (countByArray[arrayNumber] === 0) {
            --arraysIncluded;
        }
    }

    function allArraysIncluded() {
        return arraysIncluded === arrayCount;
    }

    function extractValue(item) {
        return item.value;
    }

    function saveSpread(start, end) {
        result.push(items.slice(start, end).map(extractValue));
    }

    // First item is already included.
    includeItem(0);

    while (j < (itemCount - 1)) {

        // grow j while you can
        while ((spread <= range) && (j < (itemCount - 1))) {
            ++j;
            spread += items[j].value - items[j - 1].value;
            includeItem(j);
        }
        if (spread <= range) {
            // We ran out of items and the range is still OK, break out early:
            break;
        }
        // Don't include the last item for checking:
        excludeItem(j);
        if (allArraysIncluded()) {
            saveSpread(i, j);
        }

        // Include the violating item back and try to reduce the spread:
        includeItem(j);
        while ((spread > range) && (i < j)) {
            spread -= items[i + 1].value - items[i].value;
            excludeItem(i);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    // last check after exiting the loop (j === (itemCount - 1))
    if (allArraysIncluded()) {
        saveSpread(i, j + 1);
    }

    return result;
}


function test(arrays, range) {
    var result = findRanges(arrays, range);
    document.write("<br>arrays:", JSON.stringify(arrays));
    document.write("<br>range:", range);
    document.write("<br>result:", JSON.stringify(result));
    document.write("<br>---");
}


test([[100, 110, 200, 300, 400], [40, 90, 99, 150, 200], [101, 202, 404, 505]], 15);
test([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [55, 84]], 5);
test([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50]], 10);
test([[15, 30, 699], [16, 800], [10, 801], [11, 803]], 10);

// A large test (1 million items):
var LARGE_TEST_SIZE = 1000;

var largeTest = (function () {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < LARGE_TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
        var innerArray = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < LARGE_TEST_SIZE; ++j) {
            innerArray.push((i + j) * 10);
        }
        array.push(innerArray);
    }
    return array;
})();
var startTime
startTime = Date.now();
document.write('<br>' + findRanges(largeTest, 20).length); // 3        
document.write('<br>Duration [ms]: ' + (Date.now() - startTime));
```

**Speed comparison, with different browsers**

Machine: Win 7/64, Core i7-2600 3.40 GHz

```
Version      IE 11       Chrome 45.0  Firefox 40.0.3
------- -------------- -------------- --------------
DzinX        375 ms         688 ms        1323 ms
Nina         335 ms         122 ms         393 ms
```

Comment: Oh wow, suddenly more answers showing up xD Have to go for a bit right now, but as I commented on my other answer, will be posting a small bounty on this question in a days time and will have to still figure out to whom I will award it, but absolutely splendid work!!! Do know at least that I feel immensely thankful! I fear I am going to spend all evening just trying to figure out how these answers work. At the very least though your answer seems to follow more the logic I was trying myself in the last hour or so, but it's still quite a bit different as well :)))

Comment: This solution has quadratic complexity: it runs for more than a minute (I didn't wait until the end) on input with 1000000 items.

Comment: This gives incorrect results for `getIntersectingRanges([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 2)`. It returns: `[[[0,1,2],[1,2],[2]],[[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3]],[[2],[2,3],[2,3,4]]]`, while it should be: `[[0,1,1,2,2,2],[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],[2,2,2,3,3,4]]`

Comment: the result is exactly that, what is expected, just differently grouped.

Comment: @DzinX with that input you should also get [ 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 ] right?

Comment: @NinaScholz You're right, sorry, didn't notce that.

Comment: @CharlieLiangYuan that answer is a subset of [1,1,2,2,2,3,3], so no, because we're looking for maximal sets.

Comment: This code gives incorrect results for test: `intersection([[100, 110, 200], [40, 90, 99, 150, 200], [101, 202]], 15)`. It should return 3 arrays (`[[90,99,100,101],[99,100,101,110],[200,200,202]]`), but it only returns the first two.

Comment: @DzinX, thank you, is fixed now. it was a problem with the last item. (it was leftover from the other solution).

Comment: Still not working, now fails for test: `intersection([[0,5,10,15],[1,6,11],[2,7,12],[3,8,13],[4,9,14]], 10)` - gives 12 arrays instead of 6.

Comment: How so? There are numbers from 0 to 15. With a range of 10, there are at most 6 ranges: 0-10, 1-11, 2-12, 3-13, 4-14, 5-15, regardless of the contents of the table. In this particular example, the ranges are "full", i.e. the correct result contains all the numbers from 0 to 10, then from 1 to 11, ... , then from 5 to 15.

Comment: no, that is not right, it is sufficient, if one value is contained in one of all 4 arrays. so the last set with the values of 11, 12,13,14,15 is correct, because all values are in the range **and** all values are from all arrays.

Comment: No. Quoting OP: "[...] which would return all ranges of max 'width' of range containing 1 or more elements from all arrays". Those arrays are not max 'width' (i.e. containing the maximum number of elements while still satisfying the range constraint and containing at least one element from each array). Also, with your reasoning, the original OP's example would return 5 arrays instead of 3.

Comment: @DzinX, thank you, i have not respected the sub sets.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is actually solvable in `n*log(n) + len(result)` time, with `n` being the sum of the input arrays' lengths. The algorithm works as follows:

1. Join all arrays into one array (`items`), remembering, for each value, which array it was from (`items[i].arrayNumber`)
2. Sort all items according to their values (here's where `n*log(n)` is from)
3. Keep a bunch of counters:

   - `i` and `j` are the beginning and end (inclusive) of the currently analyzed range of items (i.e. indexes of the `items` array)
   - `countByArray` counts how many items from each array are in range `[i, j]` (inclusive)
   - `arraysIncluded` counts how many arrays are "used" in the currently analyzed range (i.e. how many values of `countByArray` are positive)
   - `spread` means the difference between the lowest and highest value in the currently analyzed range
4. Now go through the whole `items` array, using `i` and `j` as markers for currently analyzed range:

   - grow the range (increase `j`) while the spread is not more than given `range` argument
   - if, in the currently analyzed range, items from all arrays are included, add the current range to the result (that's where `len(result)` complexity is from)
   - now shrink the range (increase `i`) until the spread is less or equal `range` again

This way, you produce all the maximal ranges satisfying the range condition.

The code:

```js
function findRanges(arrays, range) {

  // Gather all items into one array:
  var items = [];
  arrays.forEach(function (array, arrayNumber) {
    array.forEach(function (item) {
      items.push({
        value: item,
        arrayNumber: arrayNumber
      });
    });
  });

  items.sort(function (left, right) {
    return left.value - right.value;
  });

  var countByArray = [];
  arrays.forEach(function () {
    countByArray.push(0);
  });

  var arraysIncluded = 0;

  var i = 0,
    j = 0, // inclusive
    spread = 0,
    arrayCount = arrays.length,
    itemCount = items.length,
    result = [];

  function includeItem(pos) {
    var arrayNumber = items[pos].arrayNumber;
    ++countByArray[arrayNumber];
    if (countByArray[arrayNumber] === 1) {
      ++arraysIncluded;
    }
  }

  function excludeItem(pos) {
    var arrayNumber = items[pos].arrayNumber;
    --countByArray[arrayNumber];
    if (countByArray[arrayNumber] === 0) {
      --arraysIncluded;
    }
  }

  function allArraysIncluded() {
    return arraysIncluded === arrayCount;
  }

  function extractValue(item) {
    return item.value;
  }

  function saveSpread(start, end) {
    result.push(items.slice(start, end).map(extractValue));
  }

  // First item is already included.
  includeItem(0);

  while (j < (itemCount - 1)) {

    // grow j while you can
    while ((spread <= range) && (j < (itemCount - 1))) {
      ++j;
      spread += items[j].value - items[j - 1].value;
      includeItem(j);
    }
    if (spread <= range) {
      // We ran out of items and the range is still OK, break out early:
      break;
    }
    // Don't include the last item for checking:
    excludeItem(j);
    if (allArraysIncluded()) {
      saveSpread(i, j);
    }

    // Include the violating item back and try to reduce the spread:
    includeItem(j);
    while ((spread > range) && (i < j)) {
      spread -= items[i + 1].value - items[i].value;
      excludeItem(i);
      ++i;
    }
  }

  // last check after exiting the loop (j === (itemCount - 1))
  if (allArraysIncluded()) {
    saveSpread(i, j + 1);
  }

  return result;
}


function test(arrays, range) {
  var result = findRanges(arrays, range);
  console.log("arrays:", JSON.stringify(arrays));
  console.log("range:", range);
  console.log("result:", JSON.stringify(result));
  console.log("---");
}


test([[100, 110, 200, 300, 400], [40, 90, 99, 150, 200], [101, 202, 404, 505]], 15);
test([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [55, 84]], 5);
test([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50]], 10);
test([[15, 30, 699], [16, 800], [10, 801], [11, 803]], 10);

// A large test (1 million items):
var LARGE_TEST_SIZE = 1000;

var largeTest = (function () {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < LARGE_TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
    var innerArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < LARGE_TEST_SIZE; ++j) {
      innerArray.push((i + j) * 10);
    }
    array.push(innerArray);
  }
  return array;
})();

console.log(findRanges(largeTest, 20).length); // 3
console.log("DONE.");
```

I've extracted a bunch of functions out for better clarity. The only difference is that the output ranges are sorted (i.e. the result of the original example is `[[90, 99, 100, 101], [99, 100, 101, 110], [200, 200, 202]]`, but this is trivial to fix (just add another property to the items: `originalPosition`, and sort by this position before adding to the result in the `saveSpread` function). I can include that fix if OP feels it's important.

**Edit**: added a large test with 1mln items as performance proof (under a second on my machine).

**Edit 2**: Fixed an edge case for when the range is larger than all items.

**Edit 3**: Another interesting performance test:

```
var NEW_LARGE_TEST_SIZE = 100000;
var newLargeTestRange = 10;

var newLargeTest = (function () {
  var array = [];
  var testSize = NEW_LARGE_TEST_SIZE;
  for (var i = 0; i < testSize; ++i) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  var result = [];
  var arrayCount = newLargeTestRange / 2;
  for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; ++i) {
    result.push([]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < testSize; i += 1) {
    result[i % arrayCount].push(i);
  }
  return result;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will suit your needs:

```js
function getIntersectingRanges(arrays, range) {

    var finalResult = [];      // Final result.
    var finalResultIndex = 0;  // Current index of final result.
            
    // Looping through all input arrays.
    for (var arraysIndex = 0; arraysIndex < arrays.length; arraysIndex++) {

        var compareFromArray = arrays[arraysIndex]; // Array we're comparing from.

        // Looping through all elements of the array we're comparing from.
        for (var compareFromIndex = 0; compareFromIndex < compareFromArray.length; compareFromIndex++) {

            var coreElement = compareFromArray[compareFromIndex]; // Core element of our range search.
            var previouslyMatchedIndex = -1; // Index of previously matched array.

            /* Inner result array is created for each element in the current array. Core element is starting *
             * point of our range comparison and therefore is inserted in inner result initially.            */
            var innerResult = [coreElement];

            // Current index of the inner array. Starting from one because inner result array has core element initially.
            var innerResultIndex = 1;

            /* Total number of matched arrays. We consider inner result as part of final result  *
             * only when it contains at least one element from each input array. In other words, *
             * number of total arrays matched must be the same as input array length. Starting   *
             * at one because current array element will always match itself.                    */
            var totalArraysMatched = 1;

            // Looping through all input arrays and searching for every element in range of current element from the current array.
            for (var allArraysIndex = 0; allArraysIndex < arrays.length; allArraysIndex++) {

                var compareToArray = arrays[allArraysIndex]; // Current input array we're comparing to.

                // Looping through all elements of the current compare to array.
                for (var compareToIndex = 0; compareToIndex < compareToArray.length; compareToIndex++) {

                    // If we're comparing core element to other elements inside the same array, skip comparing element to itself.
                    if (allArraysIndex == arraysIndex && compareFromIndex == compareToIndex)
                        continue;

                    var compareToElement = compareToArray[compareToIndex]; // Current element we're comparing to.
                    var isMatch = true // Current element is match until proven otherwise.

                    // Looping through inner result array to check if current element is inside range of every other element.
                    for (var innerResultIndex = 0; innerResultIndex < innerResult.length; innerResultIndex++) {

                        var innerElement = innerResult[innerResultIndex]; // Inner result element we're currently comparing to.

                        // Check if current element is inside range of inner element. If it's not, set flag to false and don't compare any further.
                        if (compareToElement < (innerElement - range) || compareToElement > (innerElement + range)) {
                            isMatch = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isMatch) {

                        /* When element is match, set previously matched index to current arary index if it hasn't *
                         * been set for the current array yet. Do not increment array match for the array itself.  */
                        if (allArraysIndex !== arraysIndex && previouslyMatchedIndex !== allArraysIndex) {

                            totalArraysMatched++;
                            previouslyMatchedIndex = arraysIndex;
                        }

                        // Add compare to element inside inner result array and increment its index.
                        innerResult[innerResultIndex] = compareToElement;
                        innerResultIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }

            // If inner result array contains at least one element from each array proceed further. 
            if (totalArraysMatched === arrays.length) {

                var arrayDoesNotExist = true; // Array is considered non-existing until proven otherwise.
                innerResult.sort(); // Sorting array for easier comparsion.

                // Looping through all arrays in final result.
                for (var index = 0; index < finalResult.length; index++) {

                    // All arrays in final result are already sorted, so no need to sort it.
                    var existingArray = finalResult[index];

                    // Arrays with different length can't be the same.
                    if (existingArray.length !== innerResult.length)
                        continue;

                    var sameArrays = true; // Arrays are considered the same for easier logic check after.

                    // Compare all elements between arrays. Since they are sorted, we can compare elements at same index.
                    for (var elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < innerResult.length; elementIndex++) {

                        var compareToElement = existingArray[elementIndex];
                        var innerResultElement = innerResult[elementIndex];

                        // If any element is different, arrays are not the same so we can set flag to false break out of further elements comparison.
                        if (compareToElement !== innerResultElement) {

                            sameArrays = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // When array is the same as any array in final result, set flag to false and break out from further checking.
                    if (sameArrays) {

                        arrayDoesNotExist = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Add array if it doesn't exist.
                if (arrayDoesNotExist) {

                    finalResult[finalResultIndex] = innerResult;
                    finalResultIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return finalResult;
}
```

**Input:**

---

**Arrays:** `[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [55, 84]]`

**Range:** `5`

---

**Arrays:** `[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50]]`

**Range:** `10`

---

**Arrays:** `[[15, 30, 699], [16, 800], [10, 801], [11, 803]]`

**Range:** `10`

---

**Arrays:** `[[100, 110, 200, 300, 400], [40, 90, 99, 150, 200], [101, 202, 404, 505]]`

**Range:** `15`

---

**Output:**

[image: Outputs]

Comment: Hmm, didn't have time to delve into it deeply yet (saw it 2 minutes ago), but when running it on the first example it returns [400, 404] as a range as well which doesn't satisfy 'contains at least one element from each input range'. Oh and, you missed a return statement and I think all the cases of '15' should be replaced with `range`.

Comment: @DavidMulder Guess I missed that contains at least one element from each input range part. Fixed range and return for now. :)

Comment: Including that first problem of it returning an array with two elements for an input of 3 arrays? But man oh man, I am having trouble figuring out how you even got this close~ totally different approach from how I started, so have to switch my perspective a bit :))

Comment: @DavidMulder I added that contains at least one element from each input range logic. Check it out :)

Comment: You sir just earned yourself a bounty (if I forget putting it up in two days time once I am allowed to an you do remember, do say) xD It's not perfect (e.g. running it on my first example it misses `100` in `[110, 99, 101]`), but it's still really quite neat indeed and closer than I had gotten after messing around with it the entire weekend intermittently. (Only reason you could miss the bounty is if somebody comes up with a better answer... which I am not really expecting :P )

Comment: @DavidMulder I simply couldn't let it go. It was an interesting task. This final update should work for any case :)

Comment: Oh my goodness, that code is HUGE xD I am so tempted right now to post this as a codegolf just to see how short someone would be able to golf it :P

Comment: @DavidMulder haha, it's not that huge when you remove comments :P

Comment: @DavidMulder I wondered if you managed to shorten it or did you leave it as it is and does it work for you in all of your test cases?

Comment: This solution has quadratic or worse complexity: it runs for more than a minute (I didn't wait until the end) on input with 1000000 items.

Comment: This gives empty result for `getIntersectingRanges([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 2)`. It returns: `[]`, while it should be: `[[0,1,1,2,2,2],[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],[2,2,2,3,3,4]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a1 = [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [55, 84]];
var a2 = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50]];
var a3 = [[15, 30, 699], [16, 800], [10, 801], [11, 803]];

var range;
function applyArray( result, ar ) {
  var newResArrayList = [];
  result.forEach( function( resArray ) {
    var max = Math.max.apply(null,[].concat(resArray));
    var min = Math.min.apply(null,[].concat(resArray));
    ar.forEach( function(arv) {
       if((arv<=min+range)&&(arv>=max-range)) {
          newResArrayList.push([].concat(resArray).concat(arv));
       }
    });
  });
  return newResArrayList;
}

range = 5;
console.log(a1.reduce( applyArray ));
range = 10;
console.log(a2.reduce( applyArray ));
range = 10;
console.log(a3.reduce( applyArray ));
```

and output :

```
[ [ 50, 55 ], [ 60, 55 ], [ 80, 84 ] ]
[ [ 30, 40 ] ]
[ [ 15, 16, 10, 11 ] ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
/*
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677714/range-based-intersection-of-n-number-of-arrays
*/

var getIntersectingRanges = function(arrays, range) {
  // Takes arrays [[a, b], [d]] and returns [[0, a], [0, b], [1, d]].
  // First parameter represents row.
  var flatten = function(arrays) {
    var results = [];
    arrays.forEach(function(array, i) {
      array.forEach(function(item, j) {
        results.push([i, item]);
      });
    });
    return results;
  };

  // Takes an array like [[0, a], [1, b]] and sorts by a column.
  var sortByIndex = function(array, index) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a[index] - b[index];
    });
  };

  // Finds all subsequences by walking the flat array.
  var findSubsequences = function(array) {
    var results = [];
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    while (true) {
      if (j + 1 < array.length) {
        j++;
        var nextRange = array[j][1] - array[i][1];
        if (nextRange > range) {
          results.push(array.slice(i, j));
          while (array[j][1] - array[i][1] > range) {
            i++;
          }
        }
      } else {
        var currentRange = array[j][1] - array[i][1];
        if (currentRange <= range) {
          results.push(array.slice(i, j + 1));
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    return results;
  };

  // Checks that there is at least one value from each row in arrays.
  // Assumes sorted.
  var hasAllRows = function(array) {
    var lastRow = -1;
    for (var i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; ++i) {
      if (!(lastRow === array[i][0] || lastRow + 1 === array[i][0])) {
        return false;
      }
      lastRow = array[i][0];
    }
    return array[0][0] === 0 && array[array.length - 1][0] === arrays.length - 1;
  };

  // Takes only the value. Transforms [[a, b], [c, d]] to [b, d].
  var unflatten = function(values) {
    return values.map(function(value) {
      return value[1];
    });
  };

  var subsequences = findSubsequences(sortByIndex(flatten(arrays), 1));
  var filteredByAllRows = [];

  subsequences.forEach(function(subsequence, i) {
    subsequences[i] = sortByIndex(subsequence, 0);
    if (hasAllRows(subsequences[i])) {
      filteredByAllRows.push(unflatten(subsequences[i]));
    }
  });

  return filteredByAllRows;
};

var test = function(arrays, range) {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document) {
    window.document.write('<br>------------<br>');
    window.document.write('<br>arrays:<br>', JSON.stringify(arrays));
    window.document.write('<br>range:<br>', JSON.stringify(range));
    window.document.write('<br>' + JSON.stringify(getIntersectingRanges(arrays, range)));
  } else {
    console.log('------------');
    console.log('arrays:', arrays);
    console.log('range:', range);
    console.log(getIntersectingRanges(arrays, range));
  }
};

test([
  [10, 20, 30],
  [5, 8]
], 10);
test([
  [0, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 3, 4]
], 2);
test([
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
  [55, 84]
], 5);
test([
  [10, 20, 30],
  [40, 50]
], 10);
test([
  [15, 30, 699],
  [16, 800],
  [10, 801],
  [11, 803]
], 10);
test([
  [100, 110, 200, 300, 400],
  [40, 90, 99, 150, 200],
  [101, 202, 404, 505]
], 15);
```

```js
var getIntersectingRanges = function(arrays, range) {
    // Takes arrays [[a, b], [d]] and returns [[0, a], [0, b], [1, d]].
    // First parameter represents row.
    var flatten = function(arrays) {
        var results = [];
        arrays.forEach(function(array, i) {
            array.forEach(function(item, j) {
                results.push([i, item]);
            });
        });
        return results;
    };

    // Takes an array like [[0, a], [1, b]] and sorts by a column.
    var sortByIndex = function(array, index) {
        return array.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a[index] - b[index];
        });
    };

    // Finds all subsequences by walking the flat array.
    var findSubsequences = function(array) {
        var results = [];
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;

        while (true) {
            if (j + 1 < array.length) {
                j++;
                var nextRange = array[j][1] - array[i][1];
                if (nextRange > range) {
                    results.push(array.slice(i, j));
                    while (array[j][1] - array[i][1] > range) {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                var currentRange = array[j][1] - array[i][1];
                if (currentRange <= range) {
                    results.push(array.slice(i, j + 1));
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return results;
    };

    // Checks that there is at least one value from each row in arrays.
    // Assumes sorted.
    var hasAllRows = function(array) {
        var lastRow = -1;
        for (var i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; ++i) {
            if (!(lastRow === array[i][0] || lastRow + 1 === array[i][0])) {
                return false;
            }
            lastRow = array[i][0];
        }
        return array[0][0] === 0 && array[array.length - 1][0] === arrays.length - 1;
    };

    // Takes only the value. Transforms [[a, b], [c, d]] to [b, d].
    var unflatten = function(values) {
        return values.map(function(value) {
            return value[1];
        });
    };

    var subsequences = findSubsequences(sortByIndex(flatten(arrays), 1));
    var filteredByAllRows = [];

    subsequences.forEach(function(subsequence, i) {
        subsequences[i] = sortByIndex(subsequence, 0);
        if (hasAllRows(subsequences[i])) {
            filteredByAllRows.push(unflatten(subsequences[i]));
        }
    });

    return filteredByAllRows;
};

var test = function(arrays, range) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document) {
        window.document.write('------------');
        window.document.write('arrays:', arrays);
        window.document.write('range:', range);
        window.document.write(getIntersectingRanges(arrays, range));
    } else {
        console.log('------------');
        console.log('arrays:', arrays);
        console.log('range:', range);
        console.log(getIntersectingRanges(arrays, range));
    }
};

test([[10, 20, 30], [5, 8]], 10);
test([
  [100, 110, 200, 300, 400],
  [40, 90, 99, 150, 200],
  [101, 202, 404, 505]
], 15);
test([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 2);
test([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], [55, 84]], 5);
test([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50]], 10);
test([[15, 30, 699], [16, 800], [10, 801], [11, 803]], 10);
test([[100, 110, 200, 300, 400], [40, 90, 99, 150, 200], [101, 202, 404, 505]], 15);
```

Comment: please can you make your output inside the window, because its easier to look for the result

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns too many results for the original example (e.g. `[100,90,101]`) and it hangs completely (loops forever) on my `largeTest` with `LARGE_TEST_SIZE = 10` (i.e. one with only 100 items).

Comment: Yeah I misread the original question. Will be fixing it shortly and should be a much easier implementation :)

Comment: Still wrong for `getIntersectingRanges([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 2)`: returns 4 lists instead of 3.

Comment: @DzinX ok fixed it :D